# How should I add a search method in this code

Tags: java

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int weight;
        int age;
        //arrays
        List<String> last = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> zage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> zweight = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0;
        int userInput = 0;
        //menu options
        while(userInput != 2) {

            userInput = scanner.nextInt(); // collects the user inputs
            //several switch statements to answer each menu options
            switch(userInput) {
            case 1:
```

> it saves and stores all the user inputs.

```
                System.out.println("Enter a last name, age, weight"); //stores all the user information

                    String lastName = scanner.next();
                last.add(lastName);

                age = scanner.nextInt();
                zage.add(age);

                weight = scanner.nextInt();
                zweight.add(weight); 

                break;
```

> > Need to add a search code where it will retrieve the user inputs and display it, but i'm not sure on how to do it.

```
                            case 5:
                                    System.out.println("Enter the name; Enter DONE to exit");


                                    System.out.println("FOUND!!! Last Name: " +last+ " Age: " +zage+ " Weight: " +zweight);
```

Comment: I'm relearning java so i'm a little confuse on what to do

Comment: Do you know how to get the desired search parameters, and return the results once you have them? Is the actual searching algorithm the part you're having trouble with? Or is it the fact that your results are split between three lists?

Comment: I'm actually learning how to search right now so i'm new to it. I just have to add a search code that will match the name age and weight of the person

Comment: Are you allowing the user to go through all this multiple times? You need to initialize an object that will store all your names at the beginning then. You're also going to have to relate to the user's inputted weight.

Comment: Yes the user can enter the inputs as many times as they want. Not all of my code is shown but I basically have to search the original input that was saved

Comment: Have you considered a OOP approach? having an array list of a `Person` class with `name`, `age` and `weigth` properties? This way you only have one `ArrayList` instead of three and then you can use [any search algorithm you like](http://www.java2novice.com/java-search-algorithms/).

Answer (score 1):

Your names are stored in a list so you can try this:

```
if (last.contains(searchName)) {
    String foundName = last.get(last.indexOf(searchName));
    System.out.println("FOUND!!! Last Name: " +foundName);
} else{
    System.out.println("Last Name: " +searchName+ " NOT FOUND!!! ");
}
```

Note that duplicate names may be in the list so you may want to loop over the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
String enteredLastName = scanner.next();    
for (String name : last){ 
   if (name.equals(enteredLastName ){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: He would also need the index of matched `name` in the `last` list. It would be better to use a classic for instead of a for-each.